# urltools: retrieving domains not working

Tags: r, url

I have a dataframe that has 100K URLs. Below is a subset.

```
URLs <- c("123kbk.weebly.com", 
          "123kinderstreet.weebly.com", 
          "118rocks.weebly.com",
          "100detonados.blogspot.com.br",
          "100detonados.blogspot.com.br",
          "12d3.x1.realtypromls.com",
          "15kdmh7773q7.asia.com3456.com",
          "weebly.com")

test<-data.frame(URLs)

                           URLs
1             123kbk.weebly.com
2    123kinderstreet.weebly.com
3           118rocks.weebly.com
4  100detonados.blogspot.com.br
5  100detonados.blogspot.com.br
6      12d3.x1.realtypromls.com
7 15kdmh7773q7.asia.com3456.com
8                    weebly.com
```

I then want to extract the actual domains and I get two different answers from the following functions from the `urltools` package:

```
suffix_extract(domain(test$URLs))

                           host         subdomain       domain          suffix
1             123kbk.weebly.com            123kbk       weebly             com
2    123kinderstreet.weebly.com   123kinderstreet       weebly             com
3           118rocks.weebly.com          118rocks       weebly             com
4  100detonados.blogspot.com.br              <NA> 100detonados blogspot.com.br
5  100detonados.blogspot.com.br              <NA> 100detonados blogspot.com.br
6      12d3.x1.realtypromls.com           12d3.x1 realtypromls             com
7 15kdmh7773q7.asia.com3456.com 15kdmh7773q7.asia      com3456             com
8                    weebly.com              <NA>       weebly             com
```

`blogspot.com.br` should be the domain and in this case it's the suffix.

Then I tried this example:

```
host_extract(domain(test$URLs))

                         domain            host
1             123kbk.weebly.com          123kbk
2    123kinderstreet.weebly.com 123kinderstreet
3           118rocks.weebly.com        118rocks
4  100detonados.blogspot.com.br    100detonados
5  100detonados.blogspot.com.br    100detonados
6      12d3.x1.realtypromls.com            12d3
7 15kdmh7773q7.asia.com3456.com    15kdmh7773q7
8                    weebly.com          weebly
```

When I try this, `blogspot.com.br` works but the host doesn't take `12d3.x1` and `15kdmh7773q7.asia`. It also makes `weebly` the host in the last row which I was going to use to delete those from the domain list.

Is there a better function to use to extract the domains? Or is there a way where I can use both of these function to fix the mistake it makes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it doesn't need fixing because it's not making any mistakes - it's doing exactly what each function is expected to do.

In the first case, as the `suffix` in suffix_extract suggests, it's looking for suffixes. These are not the same as domain names, or as top-level domains: a suffix is a combination of domain name and TLD where users can register domains. That's why it's pulling out the subdomain for `100detonados.blogspot.com.br`: blogspot.com and its variants are public suffixes, and can be seen in the [public suffix list](https://www.publicsuffix.org/), so it pulls out everything from blogspot on as the suffix. Weebly.com isn't registered as a suffix, but .com is - hence why .com is pulled out and weebly is left as the subdomain.

In the second case it's looking for the host, which is the lowest-level part of the domain: if you have subdomains, the lowest subdomain is the host, otherwise the domain name is the host. Again, it seems to be doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing.

What exactly are you looking to get, here? The 'domain name' as commonly understood, without any top-level or subsidiary domains, or subdomains?